# unable to get local issuer certificate vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, proxy

I am trying to install extensions for VSCode. But getting unable to get local issuer certifiate.
my settings.json

```
    // Place your settings in this file to overwrite the default settings { // Controls the font family.
"editor.fontFamily": "Consolas",

    // Controls the font size.
"editor.fontSize": 12,

    //Setting corporate proxy
"http.proxy": "http://proxy_servr:3128",
"https.proxy": "http://proxy_servr:3128",

    //Disable SSL Verification
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false }
```

Comment: I faced the same issue before, however, the cause in my case was a limitation on my Corporate network that caused VSCode to fail to connect to the certificate server. This is probably not very common but I thought I leave my comment here for other corporate employees out there :P

Answer (score 7):

In VS code:
Click File -> Preferences ->Settings

```
{
"http.proxyStrictSSL":false,
"http.proxy":"http://USERID:PASSWORD@proxy.domain.com:3128"
}
```

It appears that you have not added authentication credentials to http.proxy

Answer (score 6):

Edit `%AppData%/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json`, adding:

```js
{
    ...
    "http.proxyStrictSSL":false,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who stumbled on this post and got disappointed that their only option is to disable ssl:
I found this post helpful: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/98
Set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to point to your self-signed cert, then try to install the extension again

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers open security risks, because you are downloading from internet without checking that the [Server Certificate Chain](https://www.venafi.com/blog/how-do-certificate-chains-work) is correct. Using such practices open different [hack possibilities](https://www.venafi.com/education-center/ssl/common-ssl-attacks) that you would like to avoid.

The better way to do it is to properly configure the Server Certificate Chain on your system (this is different from OS to OS) and remove the config `"http.proxyStrictSSL":false,` from your setting.

To make this working with the extensions installation, I found that you have to override the "**Proxy Support**" for extensions. Weirdly with "**on**" doesn't work for me.

[image]
Now with this config I can download securely extensions on the host like as well in docker containers used for remote execution.

Comment: Did not work for me. I have tried all the hacks suggested but have not disabled secure HTTP (which does not sound like a good option).

Comment: If you are in a Corporate environment, check that you have the correct CA installed in your machine.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a DHCP problem on your system. I was seeing the same and similar error messages trying to update and install NPM packages in my Window WSL2 Ubuntu terminal. After running `sudo echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf` I was able to install and update packages again. I spent days trying to troubleshoot this and never thought to check for DNS issues.