# VS Code: Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/xxx': unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: visual-studio-code, certificate

VS Code (1.62.2) couldn't access to json schema to validate them. Each time I open package.json file, I got this message: "*Problems loading reference 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': Unable to load schema from 'https://json.schemastore.org/package': unable to get local issuer certificate.*"

With Chrome on same computer, I could access to 'https://json.schemastore.org/package'.
I tried different settings but without success, these is what I have in settings.json file:

```
 "http.proxy": "http://my.corporate.proxy",
  "http.proxyAuthorization": null,
  "http.proxyStrictSSL": false,
```

I tried also to set an http url to access to the package json schema but it didn't change anything

```
  "json.schemas": [
    {
      "fileMatch": ["package.json"],
      "url": "http://json.schemastore.org/package",
      "schema": true
    }
  ]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Open your browser and paste the URL _https://json.schemastore.org/package_ and see if raise the same error.

Comment: This is what I said in my post ("With Chrome on same computer, I could access to 'https://json.schemastore.org/package'.") It works

Comment: Sorry, I don't read the part. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921875/unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-vscode)

Comment: Yes, I did but and applied these settings but same failure, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mine was caused by the JSON Editor plugin.  Here (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/36197) it describes some settings that are needed, but disabling the plugin proved the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Add an environment variable named `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` with the value being the path to a PEM file containing the certificate chain. Node.js is lacking trust for the certificate being used for the TLS connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Daniel , unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. And also perhaps I miss somethnig but it looks more like a VS Code issue than a node one, am I wrong?